# How to get app's node_modules absolute path from my NPM package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, path, package

I'm creating a NPM package (see https://github.com/a-barbieri/fastline it's very bare bones at the moment).

Once installed on a Node application, the package should allow the developer to copy files from a directory within the package itself or other node packages.

Now, **how can I get `node_modules` absolute path of the application whose my package is a dependency?**

I've been using `__dirname`, which works on tests within the package, but it does not work once the package becomes a dependency. At that point __dirname refers to the `package.json` of the application.

Comment: If your pkg is installed as a project dependency then your code is going to be nested within within the `node_modules` directory of the project that is consuming your pkg. Consider inferring it from `__dirname`, by splitting the path using _'node_modules'_ as the separator string and obtain the array item at index 0 (i.e. the path to the project dir that is consuming your pkg). Then use `path.join` to join _'node_modules'_ with the project dir path. For example: `const path = require('path'); const nodeModulesAbsPath = ((d) => path.join(__dirname.split(d)[0], d))('node_modules');`

Comment: Not sure why I got downvoted... my answer 100% worked.. I even published an NPM package showing how it worked........ `path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules');` is all you need!

Comment: I've found out that the issue is due to Rollup, which compiles the package code before publishing it. Rollup doesn't keep the directory tree, but moves everything into a single file which modifies `__dirname` value.

Comment: @MattOestreich -  `path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules');` works if that code exists in a file which is located at the top level of the project directory, i.e. at the same level as _package.json_. However, in the scenario that the OP mentions their code files are going to be nested within within the node_modules directory of the project that is consuming their pkg.

Comment: @RobC that's definitely a good starting point: it works from any point in the directory tree as you said.

Comment: @MattOestreich the solution works as well, but force me to run the code from a file and store the string in a constant to be used elswhere. Not that complicated, just a different approach.

Comment: @RobC so if the file that is using `__dirname` is 2 levels deep, you just do: `path.resolve(__dirname, '../../node_modules');`... I don't understand why y'all are overthinking this.

Comment: @MattOestreich - Yes sure, stepping back _n_ levels (i.e. `../`) is fine if/when you know how many levels to step back. Can you share the link to the pkg you published?

Comment: If you're publishing a package... and you have a file thats finding `node_modules` as part of your package.... wouldn't you know how many levels deep that file is? Or am I missing something?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/find-absolute-node-modules-path

Comment: @MattOestreich I compile the source before publishing the package, which shrinks the entire source tree into one file on a different directory. In my specific case it goes from `src/config` to `dist`. So if I was using your script I would have placed it in `src` (which is on the same level of `dist`) and stored the path as a constant to be used elsewhere to avoid managing the number of `../`.

Comment: I guess there is something I am not understanding then.. How many times do you install a dependency for something you're working on, and then move it around? Idk what I'm missing, but it's clear we aren't on the same page.